# python calling a class method without initializing the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I want to call a function from a python class but it would be necessary to initialize it so is there a way to call class methods without initializing the class. I have a js background I what I want is similar to this

```
class foo {
  static calculate() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Most people unfamiliar with Python use "class method" to refer to a method belonging to a class (regardless of its type), rather than a `classmethod` specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@staticmethod` decorator to define static methods in python:

```py
class Class:
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        print("Method called")

Class.method()
```